# How to automate an app to run daily in OSX

Tags: macos, applescript

I am very new to AppleScript programming. This is my code to open an app at 6 PM. I saved this code an as application, and now I want to open this application automatically daily at 6 PM without any user interaction. I want to do this programmatically; no cron job, no Automator, no calendar, no user preferences settings. I want code to trigger it. Is it possible?

```
set targetTime to "6:00:00 PM"


display dialog targetTime -- wait until we reach the target date/time
repeat while (current date) is less than date targetTime
    -- should be 60

end repeat


tell application "Myapp"

    activate

end tell

-- get the time in the desired format
on getTimeInHoursAndMinutes()

    -- Get the "hour"
    set timeStr to time string of (current date)
    set Pos to offset of ":" in timeStr
    set theHour to characters 1 thru (Pos - 1) of timeStr as string
    set timeStr to characters (Pos + 1) through end of timeStr as string

    -- Get the "minute"
    set Pos to offset of ":" in timeStr
    set theMin to characters 1 thru (Pos - 1) of timeStr as string
    set timeStr to characters (Pos + 1) through end of timeStr as string

    --Get "AM or PM"
    set Pos to offset of " " in timeStr
    set theSfx to characters (Pos + 1) through end of timeStr as string

    return (**strong text**theHour & ":" & theMin & " " & theSfx) as string
end getTimeInHoursAndMinutes
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While I appreciate Mark Setchell's answer, since you're already using applescript then just calculate the seconds until 6PM in applescript. There's no need to have a special shell script just to calculate time. Try this...

```
set targetTime to "6:00:00 PM"
display dialog targetTime -- wait until we reach the target date/time

set curTime to current date
set futureTime to date (targetTime)
set secondsToFutureTime to futureTime - curTime

-- check if it's after 6PM on the current day
-- and if so then get 6PM on the next day
if secondsToFutureTime is less than 0 then
    set futureTime to futureTime + (1 * days)
    set secondsToFutureTime to futureTime - curTime
end if

delay secondsToFutureTime

tell application "Myapp" to activate
```

Comment: @regulus : really this is very nice and easy way to do this. have my vote :)

Comment: What is the benefit between using a basic delay and an idle handler?  Seems like using delay is often better

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to do this is with `launchctl` and `launchd`, by the way.

I am no Applescript expert at all but it is generally considered poor practice to sit busy-waiting thrashing the CPU repeatedly checking the time - it is normally better to work out how long it is till you want to do something and then just sleep without consuming any CPU till that time.

I normally do things in the `bash` shell as it seems simpler to me, so I would convert the times to seconds since the Unix Epoch (1st Jan 1970) and then everything is simple, whole numbers of seconds. So, if you go in Terminal and type

```
date +%s
1420711428
```

it is currently 1420711428 seconds since the Epoch. If I want to know the time in seconds since the Epoch at 18:00 tonight, I just type this in Terminal:

```
date -j 1800.00 +%s
1420740000
```

Now, i can see I need to wait 1420740000 - 1420711428 seconds till 18:00. I  can do that easily in a shell script, and also convert your `18:00:00` into the format that the `date` command expects like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
#
# Get seconds till time specified by parameter
# Usage:
# till 18:00:00
# 
# Get current time in seconds since epoch
now=$(/bin/date +%s)
#echo now: $now

# Get passed in time in seconds since epoch
# Remove first colon and change second to a dot, so 18:00:00 becomes 1800.00 like "date" expects
t=${1/:/}
t=${t/:/.}
then=$(/bin/date -j $t +%s)
#echo then: $then

# Calculate difference
diff=$((then-now))
echo $diff
```

I then save that as `till` and make it executable with

```
chmod +x till
```

then I can do

```
./till 18:00:00
28282
```

and see it is 28282 seconds till 18:00:00.

So, I would paste the script above inside your Applescript and then use

```
do shell script "<pasted code>"
```

and simply wait the number of seconds till you want, or change the last line of the script to `sleep $diff` so the script doesn't finish till your timer expires.